# Opening image URI's in arraylist with stock gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

I have an arrayList with URI's and i want an intent to open it with gallery.

This is what i have now:

```
public void btnChoosePhotosClick(View v){

    ArrayList<String> selectedItems = imageAdapter.getCheckedItems();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Total photos selected: "+selectedItems.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "Selected Items: " + selectedItems.toString());

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + selectedItems), "image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

But this just opens empty gallery with the text "no thumbnail"

**GetCheckItems()**

```
public ArrayList<String> getCheckedItems() {
        ArrayList<String> mTempArry = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0;i<mList.size();i++) {
            if(mSparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {
                mTempArry.add(mList.get(i));
            }
        }

        return mTempArry;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Strings, try to get the Uri

```
// Instead of Strings, return the Uri of each file.
ArrayList<Uri> selectedItems = imageAdapter.getCheckedItems();
```

There is a method called: `Uri.fromFile(file);`

If you manage to pass the files Uri on your `imageAdapter.getCheckedItems();` it should work.

**Try this on your Intent:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setType("image/*"); /* All Image Types */
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, selectedItems);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i get this error: Error:(101, 15) error: method putParcelableArrayListExtra in class Intent cannot be applied to given types;
required: String,ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>
found: String,ArrayList<String>
reason: actual argument ArrayList<String> cannot be converted to ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> by method invocation conversion

Comment: Are you getting the files uri? You should pass the files and then use. Uri.getFromFile(file), Instead of Strings, get the all the files URI and pass an ArrayList<Uri> selectedItems and it should work.

Comment: Do you know any place i can see an example or how to do what you're talking about because i'm quite confused.

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550557/android-action-view-multiple-images

Comment: show me your imageAdapter.getCheckedItems(); method

Comment: added the get checkedItems to original post