# How can I set Images in Uri

Tags: android, android-studio

First of all I have two activity one is mainActivity and the second is FullscreenImage Activity.
The main thing is that what I want, to pass all the arraylist images to imageUri and how can I do that.

As example:
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator+"/......jpg");

Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

```
  List<photo> mList = new ArrayList<>();
        mList.add(new photo(R.drawable.a));
        mList.add(new photo(R.drawable.b));
        mList.add(new photo(R.drawable.c));
        mList.add(new photo(R.drawable.d));
        mList.add(new photo(R.drawable.e));
```

Comment: Are you passing a list of images or drawables?

Comment: Try this  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730244/opening-image-uris-in-arraylist-with-stock-gallery

Comment: @Praveen at the moment I am passing the drawables images but i want to convert to list of images and pass through Uri so that i could get the image in fullscreenActivity through intent to show that image in fullscreenimage